# How do I use a switch to offset the start of a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement, offset, alternate

I am trying to make a game of checkers, and right now I'm building the board. The board is a 2-dimensional array of integers that I'm changing based on where the pieces should be.

```
    // Sets up Red Pieces
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    
    for (j = k; j < 8; j += 2)
    {
        // Red piece is on square at coords [i][j]
        Board_Squares[i][j] += 2;

    }
    printf("\n");

    // k starts at 0, and in switch should alternate between 1 and 0, 
    switch (k)
    {
    case 0:
        k = 1;
    case 1:
        k = 0;
    }
}
```

However, this code only gives me this:

```
0 2 0 2 0 2 0
0 2 0 2 0 2 0
0 2 0 2 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Any help would be dope. Warning: I might be dumb.

Also, is using the switch statement the right move here anyways?

Comment: You don't `break;` in your switch. Worthwhile read: [How to debug small programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Comment: What is `MAX` and `R`? How is `Board_Squares` defined? Please show us a [mre].

Comment: `k = k ? 0 : 1;` is concise, `k = k == 1 ? 0 : 1;` is probably better.

Comment: after you answer everyone elses question, could you tell me what should the output be?

Comment: You could start the inner loop at `j = i % 2` or `j = i & 1` instead of `j = k`, then you wouldn't need `k` at all.

Comment: switch is not to be understood as 'switch the content of a variable'. It is generally used if, depending on some value of variable, you want different code blocks to run. Not 'I like to switch the value of some variable', though you could use it like that. I might wrongly assumed your (mis)understanding here.

Comment: I decided to not be dumb and changed my lousy variables for numbers so y'all can read it. Also, thanks, I now understand how clueless I am :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in your code comes from missing `break` statements: the code for a `case` fall through to the code for the next case.

Modify it this way:

```
    switch (k) {
      case 0:
        k = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        k = 0;
        break;
    }
```

The same toggling effect can be obtained with simple expressions:

- `k = 1 - k;`
- `k ^= 1;`
- `k = !k;`
- `k = k == 0;`

Or some more convoluted and obscure ones:

- `k = !!!k;`
- `k = k ? 0 : 1;`
- `k = (k + 1) & 1;`
- `k = "\1"[k];`
- `k = k["\1"];`
- `k = 1 / (1 + k);`

The checker board cells can also be initialized directly to `0` and `1` as:

```
Board_Squares[i][j] = (i + j) & 1;
```